# Mysqli_query works in one part of if-elseif statement, but not the other

Tags: php, mysqli

I am working on an event list page for a class I am taking. This is one of the first time I have worked with PHP.

I want to display a filtered list of events depending on the category chosen from a drop down list. I also want to display a complete list of events if 'All Events' is chosen from the DDL. I have an if-elseif statement that will change the sql query depending on the category value from the query string.

The specific error that I am seeing is that the list of events is missing when 'All events' is selected. The echo statement of the if-else DOES work, and it IS displaying the correct values for the $category, $month, and $year. What is missing is the table containing the list of events.

Note: I have tested the query and have confirmed that it does work to pull a list of all events. I have also tried this with an empty $category value with no change.

This is the IF statement that DOES work:

```
if(!empty($category)){

$catresult = mysqli_query($con,"
SELECT cal_events.event_id, 
    cal_events.title, 
    DATE_FORMAT(cal_dates.date, '%M %D %Y') AS formatted_date, 
    MONTHNAME('$month') AS NameOfMonth
    FROM cal_events 
LEFT JOIN cal_dates 
ON cal_events.event_id = cal_dates.event 
WHERE cal_events.categories = '$category' 
AND YEAR(date) = '$year' 
AND MONTH(date) = '$month' 
GROUP BY cal_dates.date, cal_events.title, cal_events.event_id");

echo "<h2>$category</h2>
<h3>Events for $monthName, $year</h3>
<br /><br />
<table align='center'>
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Event</th>
<th></th>
</tr>";

}
```

This is the ELSEIF statement that DOES NOT work:

```
elseif($category=='All'){


    $catresult = mysqli_query($con,"
SELECT cal_events.event_id, 
    cal_events.title, 
    DATE_FORMAT(cal_dates.date, '%M %D %Y') AS formatted_date, 
    MONTHNAME('$month') AS NameOfMonth
FROM cal_events 
LEFT JOIN cal_dates 
ON cal_events.event_id = cal_dates.event 
WHERE YEAR(date) = '$year' 
AND MONTH(date) = '$month' 
GROUP BY cal_dates.date, cal_events.title, cal_events.event_id");

echo "<h2>$category</h2>
<h3>Events for $monthName, $year</h3>
<br /><br />
<table align='center'>
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Event</th>
<th></th>
</tr>";

}
```

This is the while loop that is displaying the list of events:

```
//Displays the list of events
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($catresult))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['formatted_date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='detail.php?id=".$row['event_id']."' target='_blank'>" . 
$row['title'] . "</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if/elseif` logic isn't mutually exclusive:

```
if(!empty($category)){
  //...
}
elseif($category=='All'){
  //...
}
```

If the `$category` value is `'ALL'` then the *first* `if` block will still execute.  So under no conditions will that `elseif` block *ever* execute.

You could switch around your conditions, or even just add an additional check to the first one.  Something like:

```
if(!empty($category) && $category!='All'){
```

But the point is that your `if` and `elseif` blocks have to be completely different subsets of the total set of possibilities.  If the first block executes, the second block by definition won't.

Comment: *dahhh beat me by a minute!*

Comment: Oops! I will try this. I orginally had this written as an if else with a completely empty category value (Which also did not work).

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you for the quick answer! I still want to figure out why almost this exact same code block (with an if-else, not an if-elseif) did not work with an empty category querystrng value, but you solved my problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way `elseif` works. If the first condition is true (it always will be with `category='all'`) then the second condition will never be tested.

```
if(something){
     // This runs if something is true.
}
elseif(something else){
     // This runs only if the first if is false and the elseif is true 
}
else 
    // This only runs if none of the preceding conditions equate to true. 
}
```

So adjust your syntax to be;

```
if(!empty($category) && $category !== "All"){
    ...
}
elseif($category == "All"){
    ...
}
else {
    // no category set.
}
```

> There are various other flows that can be used to define the same behaviour such as:

```
 if(!empty($category) )
     if($category == "All"){
         ... //category is All
     }
     else {
         ... //category is not All
     }
}
else {
    // category is empty.
}
```

---

You can also try using [**Switch Statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) if you want to check multiple category values specifically.

---

[**Read the PHP elseif manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php).

Comment: This did the trick. I misworded my question after slightly changing my code before posting. I originally had this as an IF-ELSE statement.